# Initializing JAXB for unmarshalling to external class definitions

Tags: class, jaxb, axis, unmarshalling

I am using Axis to generate client side service classes, and I would like to use those classes within the same runtime as the generation. I have implemented the axis generate and compile successfully. However, using reflection to instantiate and call the generated classes (with custom class loader), the jaxb unmarshall keeps returning a null (I have verified correct response xml from the service call).

It seems there needs to be some sort of initialization of the jaxb context when loading in classes in realtime (not on the classpath) from a custom classloader.

Any suggestions/insight?

Comment: It might be useful to post also your code.

Comment: Sure, how much and which parts?  There are thousands of lines.